# why SFTP client only need to know the private key, doesn't requires public key?

Tags: ssh, sftp

When I connect a SFTP server from a client, I only need to provide to the client software the private key, not the public key. I don't know how this works, because from [1] and [2], both requires the client software also know the public key.

My understanding of how SFTP work is

setup

- client: generate private/public key pairs.
- client: send public key to server
- server: add this public key to its authorized keys list

during connection

- client: tell server the public key
- server: check if the public key is authorized, if not, refuse, otherwise, send a random session id to client
- client: client use private key to encode the random session id and send to server
- server: decode it by the public key and confirm the identity.

In this case, the client requires public key. However, I didn't provide this but SFTP client still able to connect the sever. So how this SFTP protocol really works?

[1] http://www.openssh.org/txt/rfc4252.txt

[2] https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1962.php

Comment: The client computed the public key from the private key.

Comment: thank you! this explains everything. also, a side note, I can get the public key by 'ssh-keygen -y' to get the public key from private key (as I use OpenSSH)

Comment: It is so refreshing to see an actual *question* instead of "my code doesnt work plz help", I'll cast an upvote for just that

Answer (score 7):

While @Pascal Cuoq's comment is the correct answer, it is only half of the answer, since Actually, the client does need a public key - but only the *server's* public key, and you already have that in your `known_hosts` file.

If you don't - you are asked to trust the one the server is presenting on your first connection to the server. This is a thing that most people overlook completely. If you are DNS-poisoned (or there is some other form of Man-in-the-Middle attack ongoing) during the first connection - or don't pay attention to `Server identity has changed` notifications - you are vulnerable to MitM attacks.

Comment: I don't quite follow why the client maintains the private key and not the server. From the question and what i have read is that if i wish to connect to a server using keys, i'll need to generate the key pair. I keep the private key and provide the server with a copy of the public key. What you seem to be suggesting is also is that i need the server's public key which indicates that the server has a private key. Sorry, i'm confused.

Comment: @Motivated the server also has a private key called `Host Key` - it is used to authenticate the server to user just as your private key is used to authenticate you to the server

Comment: Thanks Kimvais. If i had further questions regarding SFTP, would you mind if i dropped you an email?